# Aligning Absolute positioned elements next to each other

Tags: javascript, css, css-float, css-position

All,

I want to align absolutely positioned elements next to each other. Im sure Ive seen this effect in my own code however Im struggling to reproduce the effect in my current project.

Here is layout sketch:

[image]

The absolutely positioned elements (about 100 divs) align from left to right, when they run out of space, they fall into the next row. All of this sounds like the job for floats, however, due to small tweaks to positioning, I have to go with absolute position.

My question is how can I automatically align absolute positioned divs inside a parent div.

Comment: yes ofcourse, the absolute position is required because the divs actually start from (e.g) top: -50px; left: -50px. I.e. to say that the layout starts rendering outside the viewable area, this is intentional effect in order to give the illusion of 'bigger picture'

Comment: If that's the case, go with floats in child divs, and make the parent container div `top: -50px` instead.

Comment: thanks Samuel, thought of that but the divs are extending out from all sides, i.e. from left, right, top, bottom. Floats would not let me do this. With absolute position & js, I can control how far a row should extend

Answer (score 1):

> when they run out of space, they fall into the next row

This *does not work* with absolute-positioned elements, because, well, they are absolutely positioned.

This sounds like a job for jQuery [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) plugin.

**UPDATE:**

> yes ofcourse, the absolute position is required because the divs actually start from (e.g) top: -50px; left: -50px. I.e. to say that the layout starts rendering outside the viewable area, this is intentional effect in order to give the illusion of 'bigger picture' - [Kayote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127976/aligning-absolute-positioned-elements-next-to-each-other#comment21292516_15127976)

If that's the case, go with floats in child divs, and make the parent container div top: -50px instead.

**UPDATE:**

> but the divs are extending out from all sides, i.e. from left, right, top, bottom. Floats would not let me do this. With absolute position & js, I can control how far a row should extend - [Kayote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127976/aligning-absolute-positioned-elements-next-to-each-other#comment21292578_15127976)

Then your CSS isn't done correctly. There are ways to achieve that effect. Please reproduce your code on jsfiddle.com, or link to it.

Comment: I'd rather not use any plugin as I dont think its much work... its just a concept of Absolute positioning that Im not clear on :)

Comment: just added an image to the question above, hope that helps

Comment: the divs are all of the same width & height. If you can achieve with floats, Id love to know how :)

Comment: There isnt much code to reproduce...  jsfiddle.net/zYdUz/2 this is jhunlio's example slightly modified. The question remains how to align absolute positioned elements.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```html
<div class="parentContainer">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.parentContainer {
  width: 200px;
}
.child {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Hope this works.

Here is an example on that http://bittu.github.com/hidden-tiles/

If you want to make the `child` elements go beyond the viewable screen then don't specify width to the `parentContainer`

```css
.parentContainer {
  width: auto;
}
```

Comment: thanks Sandeep, I like the idea of relative negative position but the floats are restrictive as they wont allow me to extend beyond the viewable area

Comment: +1 blocks that are positioned in absolute do not know, for example, *when they reach the end of the first row* because they're *completely* removed from the flow. Does a particular block have neighbors? He'll have no idea, he's independant from others

Comment: @FelipeAls thats where js comes in, Im not bothered about when to start a new row, I need to know how to absolute positioning works in relation to elements being siblings to each other

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner noPaddingRight "></div>

  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner noPaddingRight "></div>

</div>
```

css

```
    .wrap {
float:left;
position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}

.inner {
float:left;
margin:0 0 5px 1%;
    width:23%;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:100px;
}

.noMarginRight {margin-right:0 !important}
```

Comment: from reading your code, the 'wrap' absolute position is going to override the float left property. Inside wrap you are floating the inner children. Please see my question above for the illustration, in your example, the divs are not going to stretch to the right as per my req.

Comment: thanks for the effort jhunlio, here is my updated one: http://jsfiddle.net/zYdUz/2/ Notice, the divs donot go outside the right viewable area, which is what I want :)

Comment: hi if you can give exact position of the div and what it look like.. because i'm so confuse of what you want to achieve.